# Модификация статического поля класса

Tags: java

В public классе есть `static` поле, которое я мечтаю модифицировать (увеличить на единицу), если количество объектов класса увеличится.

```
public class Man{
   private static int allMans = 0;

   public void addMoreMans() {
     this.allMans++;   
   } 

   public static void main(String[] args){
   Man man = new Man();
   man.addMoreMans();
   } 
}
```

Так не работает. Ах да!  интеджер `allMans` статичный, какой `this`!?
  Обращаюсь через `Man.allMans` тоже не хочет. И как же к нему обращаться?

Comment: Просто `allMans++;`?

Comment: Читайте теорию... Статические переменные привязаны к классу, а не к его экземплярам, поэтому и обращаются к ним не как к полям объектам - имя объекта*точка*имя поля, а как к полям класса - имя класса*точка*имя поля. Так можно получить доступ снаружи класса, если, конечно, позволяют модификаторы доступа. А в пределах класса достаточно сделать так, как показано в предыдущем комментарии - просто имя поля.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На самом деле все варианты должны работать, если метод main в том же классе.

```
public class Man{
private static int allMans = 0;

public void addMoreMans() {
    allMans++;  
    Man.allMans++;
    this.allMans++;
} 

public static void main(String[] args){
    new Man().addMoreMans() ;
    System.out.println(Man.allMans);
 } 
}
```

результат следующий:
    3

Но если метод main у Вас находиться в другом классе например:

```
public class Mans {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Man m =new Man() ;
        m.addMoreMans();
        System.out.println(Man.allMans);
    } 
}
```

То здесь Вы не получите доступ к allMans так как у Вас переменная private.
Если поменяете на

```
 public static int allMans = 0;
```

то и здесь у Вас будет всё работать.